# Set default permission for user using copy (using winscp) in Centos 7

Tags: centos, umask

I did set umask 001 for user (ex: desmon) in /home/desmon/.bashrc

When desmond create a file then permission is -rw-rw-rw-
But when desmon use scp command to copy file then permission is -rwxr-x r--

Please show me how to lets user desmon use scp command with permission default is -rw-rw-rw- because I need other user can Read & Write the File copied by desmond

Tks all.

Answer (score 1):

`scp` does not start a shell, so that it will not get `umask` value which is written in `.bashrc`

You can use `rsync` (same syntax with `scp`) with `--chmod` option.

`rsync --chmod=F666 file myuser@192.168.1.100:/home/myuser`

Comment: Thanks mate, I may have to setup for user using RSync tool on Windows to do this.